# Segue not passing data to 2nd VC

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a view controller that populates a tableView with Course venue and date fields. I am trying to get the selected row to pass the record to the 2nd view controller where I would like to display the venue title.

the code show no errors, except the UILabel for the venueTitle in the 2nd view controller does not display the venues title.

1st ViewController -

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class CoursesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var coursesTable: UITableView!


var coursesArray: Array<CKRecord> = []

var selectedCourseIndex: Int!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    coursesTable.delegate = self
    coursesTable.dataSource = self
    fetchCourses()

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return coursesArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "courseCell", for: indexPath)
    let courseRecord: CKRecord = coursesArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = courseRecord.value(forKey: "courseVenue") as? String

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"

    let CSDate = dateFormatter.string(from: courseRecord.value(forKey: "courseDate") as! Date)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = CSDate

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40.0
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedCourseIndex = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMapDetail", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showMapDetail" {
        let coursesMap = segue.destination as! CourseMapVC
        if let index = selectedCourseIndex {
            coursesMap.courseRecord = coursesArray[index]
        }
    }
}

func fetchCourses() {
    let container = CKContainer.default()
    let publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Courses", predicate: predicate)
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "courseDate", ascending: true)]

    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print("error fetch notes \(error)")

        } else {

            print("Success")

            for result in results! {
                self.coursesArray.append(result )
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
                self.coursesTable.reloadData()
                self.coursesTable.isHidden = false
            })
        }
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

and the second view controller -

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit
import MapKit


class CourseMapVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var venueTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var courseRecord: CKRecord!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if let course = courseRecord {
        venueTitle.text = course.value(forKey: "courseTitle") as? String
    }

   let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)


}


}
```

I am not worried about the CLLocation as yet, I am more concerned about information being passed or at this stage not. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Put a breakpoint in func prepare(for segue: . How far does it get?

Comment: @Andrew,  It gets to - if segue.identifier == "showMapDetail" { but i'm not sure how that is significant?

Comment: It means the issue is with the identifier string. print("\(segue.identifer)") at this breakpoint. This may give you a clue about what is happening.

Comment: did you set up another segue directly from the table to the second VC?  That won't have the same identifier, so the code in your prepare will not be executed

Comment: That was interesting - Xcode crashed each time I ran it? Clearly as you say though that is the area of concern.

Comment: @Bowcaps you want segue on cell tap??

Comment: @AndrewMcKinley it simply displays Optional("showMapDetail"). and Russell I have a single segue from the prototype cell to the second VC, i have tried show, show detail and present modally - all have the same result, as if there is no data passed.?

Comment: Do you not make it to the next line? let coursesMap = segue.destination as! CourseMapVC

Comment: @AndrewMcKinley, no it stops in the same place, although I do get the print display twice. Also it runs straight through with the suggested code by Callam below.

Comment: Pls try this, just as an experiment. In CourseMapVC, implement `viewDidAppear`, and move `if let course = courseRecord { venueTitle.text = course.value(forKey: "courseTitle") as? String }` out of `viewDidLoad` into `viewDidAppear`. Now does it work?

Comment: matt, I think you are on to something, the viewDidAppear did not effect the outcome, but clearly the viewDidLoad is after the fact. I'm still confused??

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's the UI layout problem not Storyboard. Have you tried to debug your view yet? The label may be clipped

Comment: The layer is not clipped as per screen grab - /Users/Nige/Desktop/Simulator Screen Shot 19 Feb 2017, 00.51.36.png

Comment: The label does not appear clipped as per screen grab (in edit)

Comment: What is your segue type? Is it a custom presentation/transition? Also I think you need to make sure that `prepare(for:sender:)` get called before `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Here's a thing, you can't assume that prepare method will always be called before viewDidLoad. You need to update UI in both viewDidLoad and properties didSet

Comment: The segue type is default, changing the prepare statement before viewDidLoad made no difference

Comment: Can you try implement didSet on courseRecord property and see if that get called before `viewDidLoad` or not

Comment: What are you asking me to didSet as courseRecord is specifying a record variable from the array is it not, so what can I set before the script knows to set it? I am a little confused.

Comment: What I want to know is which code is called first, the `courseRecord` setting or `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

Your segue identifier might be incorrect. Try using the optional cast of the segue destination controller to `CourseMapVC` as the condition instead.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    switch segue.destination {
    case let controller as CourseMapVC:
        if let index = selectedCourseIndex {
            controller.courseRecord = coursesArray[index]
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: that produces the same result, although the breakpoint allows the script to complete the function prepare(for segue which is strange.

Comment: Which line are you putting the breakpoint? `controller.courseRecord = coursesArray[index]`?

Comment: I wasn't but it produces the same output, either at that line or the first function line.

Comment: what happens if you print `segue.destination` before the switch/if statement? It should print the class type, ensure it's `CourseMapVC`.

Comment: It basically produces -Optional("showMapDetail")
Optional("showMapDetail"), I do have a warning on the line though - Expression implicitly corrected from String Any

Comment: print `segue.destination` not `segue.identifier`.

Comment: Printing print(segue.destination) outside the if statement gives -  <StoryboardB.CourseMapVC: 0x7f825ecd5650> but only one line, inside the if statement it gives it twice?

Comment: I have changed the code in both controllers a little. This has resulted in an empty value being passed as the default label text is actually blank.

the changes are thus -

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedCourseIndex = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMapDetail", sender: self)
    }`

Comment: `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showMapDetail" {
            let coursesMap = segue.destination as! CourseMapVC
                if let index = selectedCourseIndex {
                    coursesMap.courseRecord = coursesArray[index]
                        let courseRecord: CKRecord = coursesArray[index]
                            cvenue = courseRecord.value(forKey: "courseVenue") as! String
            coursesMap.courseVenue = (cvenue)!
            print("Selected Venue is \(cvenue)!")

Comment: And in the second viewController 

`import UIKit
import CloudKit
import MapKit


class CourseMapVC: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var venueTitle: UILabel!

    var courseRecord: CKRecord!
    
    var courseVenue = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
            print("Course Venue - \(courseVenue)")
        
            venueTitle.text = courseVenue
    }
}`

Comment: Course Venue - 

Selected Venue is Optional("Cardiff")!

With 'Course Venue' being blank it would appear nothing is being passed or a nil value is being passed.

Answer (score 0):

Well a fresh pair of eyes (and brain) this morning and I have sorted out the Segue problem.

I needed to 
 1. Call the Array again (having done so for the tableView)
 2. Get the field courseVenue from the selected row
 3. Specify that the value was passed as a String

Thanks for all the pointers for this, here is the amended code.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showMapDetail" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! CourseMapVC
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let courses: CKRecord = coursesArray[indexPath.row]
            let coursesVenueCell = courses.value(forKey: "courseVenue")
            destinationController.courseTitle = coursesVenueCell as! String
        }
    }
}
```